# Is using main.rs as lib entry point unidiomatic?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm currently experimenting with wasm, which has to be compiled as cdylib. I don't want to maintain two entry files for the bin target and for the lib target, so I added these lines to my *Cargo.toml*:

```
[lib]
name = "sandbox"
path = "src/main.rs"
crate-type = ["cdylib"]
```

My `fn main()` has now this attribute:

```
#[cfg_attr(target_arch = "wasm32", wasm_bindgen)]
```

Everything works as expected, but cargo warns me about this:

```
warning: file found to be present in multiple build targets
```

Can this warning safely be ignored? Why?

If yes, is it possible to suppress it?

Comment: Does the `lib.rs` actually need to have a `main()` function too?

Comment: So can't you define a `mod main;` in `lib.rs` and make the `main` function public so you can import it? This seems to work for me, but I didn't try with a wasm project.

Comment: @PeterHall No, this does not work. The pathes differs between library and binary because the root module differs. Also, crate attributes doesn't work as expected. I already tried this solution before. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish. If you are targeting WASM, you don't want a main at all. Under what circumstances would you want to have a `main`?

Comment: Support fur multiple platforms